# Need an example for Normal Form

Tags: first-order-logic

We define Normal Form as:

> Given a proposition $φ$ of $FOL$ (in some fixed language $L$), $φ$ is
>   logically equivalent to a formula of the following form (called normal
>   form):
>
> $(Q_1x_1)$...$(Q_{​n}x_{​n})ψ$
>
> Where,
>
> ψ is a formula with no quantifiers occurring in it (called
>   quantifier-free), and
>
> $Q_i$ ​​ " is one or the other quantifier ($∀$ or $∃$).

We know a proposition is a statement like "For any ..., there exists ... such that..." Here is $ψ$ represent the statement "such that..."?

I want a concrete example.

Comment: I've usually seen this referred to as "prenex normal form".  Is it sometimes just called "normal form", without the "prenex"?

Comment: @Mitchell I don't think so. There are two different definitions for prenex normal form and normal form in wiki. But I didn't read the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the "such that" is implied in the notation; $\psi$ is the statement *following* the "such that".

Here's an example: $$\forall x\exists y(x<y).$$ "For all $x$, there is some $y$ such that $x<y$." Does this make things clearer?

---

Actually, "such that" is tied to the *existential quantifier* $\exists$: we wouldn't translate "$\forall x(x+1\not=x)$" as "For all $x$ such that $x+1\not=x$", but rather  "For all $x$, *it is the case that* $x+1\not=x$."

Basically, translate "$\forall x$" as "For all $x$, it is the case that" and "$\exists x$" as "There exists an $x$ such that". This will lead to lengthy translations - e.g. "$\forall x\exists y(x<y)$" translates to $$\mbox{"For all $x$, it is the case that there exists a $y$ such that $x<y$"},$$ which is a bit more complicated than "For all $x$ there is a $y$ such that $x<y$". However, it will also accurately translate the meaning of the sentence.

Comment: Good explanation. The definition says ψ is a formula with no quantifiers. So I thought such that is not a notation. But if it is tied to the existential quantifier, then it makes sense.